# Telegram Bot API SetChatMenuButton using PHP

Tags: php, php-telegram-bot

anyone can help on how can I implement changing the telegram menu button using PHP, I'm totally new using and understanding it. Any help is well appreciated. TIA. Here's what I'd done, I'm doubting about JSON serialize i'm making here. Looking forward for any help. Here's the API documentation [SetChatMenuButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchatmenubutton)

````
$data = [
    'menu_button' => array (
        "MenuButtonWebApp" => array (
            "type" => "web_app",
            "text" => "New Menu",
            "web_app" => array (
                "url" => "MYWEBSITE"
                )
            )
        )
    
    ];
   $response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/botMYAPITOKEN/setChatMenuButton? chat_id=MYCHATID&".http_build_query($data));
   print_r($response);```


Response: However I dont see any changes or additional error log if im missing something.
````

{"ok":true,"result":true}

Comment: Did you find anything? I think the setChatMenuButton function doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$data = [
        "chat_id"   => $chatId,
        'menu_button' => json_encode(
            array (
                    "type" => "web_app",
                    "text" => "Menu",
                    "web_app" => array (
                        "url" => "MYWEBSITE"
                    )
            )
        )
    ];
$response = Http::get("https://api.telegram.org/botMYAPITOKEN/setChatMenuButton?"
        .http_build_query($data));
```